# Cross-Domain iframe loading issue in SharePoint Apps

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, iframe, cross-domain

I have one SharePoint-hosted app in which I am fetching all the Site Collection list from tenant using REST api call using following snippet:

```
var spAppWebUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl;
var queryUrl = spAppWebUrl + "/_api/search/query?querytext='contentclass:sts_site'";

$.ajax({
   url: queryUrl + "'contentclass:sts_site'",
   headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
   contentType: "application/json; odata=verbose",
   success: function (sitedata) {
       // Parsing the sitedata object and getting the site collection url
       // Using url I am giving the SRC of an iframe to show the preview of the site collection.
       ....
       jQuery('results').append('<iframe src="' + url + '" name="previewFrame" id="previewFrame"></iframe>');
   }
});
```

As explained in code, I am using the Site Collection URL. I am running the app on following domain: `https://myo365domain.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/default.aspx`. On Page Load I request for result of all site collection list and hover over that item, I am showing preview in `iframe` like search results (like out of the box preview feature). But when I see the chrome browser's console I see following error:

> Refused to display 'https://myo365domain-my.sharepoint.com/personal/myo365admin_onmicrosoft_com/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/default.aspx' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

**Note**: I have full access given for tenant in my SharePoint hosted app. This error occurs only when the domain is different. So I have referred [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/officeapps/archive/2012/11/29/solving-cross-domain-problems-in-apps-for-sharepoint.aspx) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/fp179927(v=office.15).aspx) articles, but couldn't identify the issue. I am only showing preview of the result site collection in `iframe`. Does anyone know any workaround for this? Any help would be much appreciated.